# What should be set as id in DB, if there is no proper field in id-less data

Tags: sql, xml, database, database-design

I am building database from XML. Subtree of XML on specific level should be equivalent of single record.

The problem is, that in this specific subtree there is no id, or any other type of value, which is uniq for whole XML. There is also lack group of fileds, which can help my create id based on several values.

Why I need this id? Because later I will get updated version of this XML and I want to prepare mechanism, which will detect whether record with specific id changed and update it.

I thought about hash function, like MD5, but this will fail, because if specific XML subtree will change, MD5 also will also change, so new id will be useless to asking about old record in database.

I am not able to tell which fields in XML subtree can be changed.

Comment: What is it in the updated version of the xml will tell you that it's an updated version and not an original version of something else?

Comment: XML is generated by another mechanism (which ask library database using protocol Z39.50 and receiving data in ancient format like MARC-21). I have to manualy run mechanism which will help me generate new XML once a while. I can not predict in which order particular recods will be written to new version of XML. And since I write that there will be database of books, I have to clarify that I will get multiple records with this same ISBN, so ISBN cannot be treat as ID.

Comment: Give us a sample of an original record, an update that you believe would represent a change, and a contrasting update that would represent something new.

Comment: The problem of data that lacks an id is deeper that what you have expressed.  Some people treat the id field as identifying a row in a table.  But, ultimately, and id identifies (and acts as a surrogate for) an instance of a subject matter entity.  If two entries in your XML data has identical appearance, how would you tell which entity each one referred to?